# Having trouble to center horizontally across the screen

Tags: html, css

So, i'm super new to HTML/CSS. For my class I have to make a portfolio webiste.

I want to be very simple. So, I'm starting off with my name centered in the middle of the page, and then underneath I want it to look like this:

About Graphic Design Studio Art (but, spaced out a little obviously)

Here is my html:

```
   <!-- BEGIN: Sticky Header -->
<div id="header_container">
    <div id="header">
    </div>  
        <div id="indexheader"><a rel="title">THIS IS MY NAME</a>
        </div>
        <div id="links">
            <a rel="#about">About</a>
        </div>
        <div id="links">
            <a rel="#design">Graphic Design</a>
        </div>
        <div id="links">
            <a rel="#art">Studio Art</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END: Sticky Header -->
```

Here is my CSS:

```
/* Make Header Sticky */
#header_container { 
background:transparent;  
height:60px; 
left:0; 
position:fixed; 
width:100%; 
top: 40px;
text-align: center;

}

#header {
left: 0;
position: fixed;
right: 0;
text-align: center;
top: 160px;
z-index: 999;
float: right;

}

body.top-navigation-position-below-banner #navigation-bottom {
position: fixed; 
top: 0;
border-bottom: none;
z-index: 999;
}

#page-header-wrapper { 
margin-top: 180px;

}

#links {
height: auto;
width: 100%;
margin-top:30px;
background-color:transparent;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left:0%;
padding: 0px;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r7K26/

I also tried to make it a sticky-header. Not sure if that's right either. IM A HUGE NOOB. Forgive me.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing your div with id #header immediately, so the elements beneath is are not receiving any styling. That might be what you want, but then you have an extra  at the end of your html.

You can center your div a lot of ways, but the following should work fine:

```
#indexheader {display:block;width:100%;text-align:center;}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't need that many divs first of all. Look at this, for example:
Html:

```
<div class="myInfo">
<h1>Your Name</h1>

<ul class="myLinks">
<li><a href="..">link</a></li>
<li><a href="..">link</a></li>
<li><a href="..">link</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

And actually, you don't even need a div in this case but regardless, having the class on one div you can style with selectors such as:

```
.myInfo H1 {....}
.myInfo UL {..}
```

etc

or just
`.myLinks {}` for the url and then:
`.myLinks li {}` for the list items.

I know this is a fast answer but as you are learning, I think it might be better to 'sort of' give you some pointers instead of just doing it all, right?
:)

Answer (score 0):

You're very close, and here's one solution using your code as a base. Try this styled JSFiddle and see if its what you need. Please feel free to play around with the code, and hit the Run button when you are ready to see the results. http://jsfiddle.net/TalkingRock/MAuzN/

The structure:
The html code is simplified by using "header_container" to wrap the entire header (title and menu). The "indexheader" is placed in its own div. A new menu div now contains/wraps only the menu items.

```
<div id="header_container">
<div id="indexheader"><a href="#">THIS IS MY NAME</a></div>
<div id="menu">    
<div class="links"><a href="#">About</a></div>
<div class="links"><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></div>
<div class="links"><a href="#">Studio Art</a></div>
</div> <!-- end menu -->    
</div> <!-- end header_container -->
```

The CSS
Inline-block is used to shrink wrap, center, and display the menu items in a single line. Inline-block has a natural 4px margin around each item, and that can be removed by removing the white space in-between each inline-block item in the html code. You'll also need to add "vertical-align:top". Inline-block is a good style to learn, has good browser support, and comes in handy.

```
#header_container {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
border:0px;     
min-height:80px; /* use min-height so the div will expand around the contents, regardless of height. */
width:100%;    
background-color:transparent;
position:fixed;
top:40px;
}

#indexheader {
text-align:center;
padding:10px;    
}

#menu {
text-align:center; /* text-align center works because of the inline-block */
}

.links {
display:inline-block;
vertical-align: top
}
```

Good article on lnline-block: http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/

Inline-block support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=inline-block

Here are a few other articles you'll find useful. CSS Fixed Menus:http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/menus.en.html
The Z Index: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/

Note: The div that holds your contents needs a top padding or margin tall enough to make sure it isn't covered up by the fixed menu. Position fixed will be buggy in touch devices, especially handheld phones. In your original code there is an extra div in your html, id's can only be used once per page, use href for your links, and "backgound-color:transparent" (transparent is the default style).